# C# Json Convert в Cookie

Tags: c#, json

Есть файл Json:

```
[
{
"domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1649537509.797288,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": true,
"name": "__ddg1",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "fdDFdsgfgfGFDG432",
"id": 1
},
{
"domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1649537511.843376,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": true,
"name": "__ddg2",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "GF4234234GF",
"id": 2
 },
 {
"domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1681146260,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "_ga",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "GA1.2.3574234177.1618001510",
"id": 3
},
{
"domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1618160660,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "_gid",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "GA1.2.84654125.1618001510",
"id": 4
},
{
"domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1649537510,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "_ym_d",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "no_restriction",
"secure": true,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "3123432534",
"id": 5
 },
 {
"domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1618146260,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "_ym_isad",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "no_restriction",
"secure": true,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "1",
"id": 6
},
{
"domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1649537510,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "_ym_uid",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "no_restriction",
"secure": true,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "53452324",
"id": 7
},
{
"domain": ".www.cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1649541131.924992,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": true,
"name": "__ddgid",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "FFDSertewt2454543",
"id": 8
},
{
"domain": ".www.cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1618091531.925059,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": true,
"name": "__ddgmark",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "F43245345Gfg",
"id": 9
 },
 {
"domain": "www.cyberforum.ru",
"hostOnly": true,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "cfdup_timestamp",
"path": "/csharp-beginners",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": true,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "432545326435",
"id": 10
}
]
```

Преобразую его в Cookie:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = File.ReadLines(@"cok.json").Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cookie>(x)).ToList();
```

Выводит ошибку:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Json.jsonFileRead' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array

Comment: П о глядите на текст вашего json - это же не один объект, это массив.

Comment: `List<Cookie> cookies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cookie>>(File.ReadAllText("cok.json"));`

Comment: Вы считываете и пытаетесь десереализовать каждую строку файла отдельно, то есть первая итерация цикла Linq запросе выглядит так `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cookie>("[")`. У вас появилось исключение, выполнение кода остановилось, вы могли бы сразу посмотреть, чему равно `x` в лямбда-выражении, но по необъеснимым причинам не стали этого делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чуть чуть видоизменил Ваш JSON, чтобы было легче сделать объект.

```
    {"data":[
    {
    "domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
    "expirationDate": 1649537509.797288,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "__ddg1",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "unspecified",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "fdDFdsgfgfGFDG432",
    "id": 1
    },
    {
    "domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
    "expirationDate": 1649537511.843376,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "__ddg2",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "unspecified",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "GF4234234GF",
    "id": 2
     },
     {
    "domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
    "expirationDate": 1681146260,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ga",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "unspecified",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "GA1.2.3574234177.1618001510",
    "id": 3
    },
    {
    "domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
    "expirationDate": 1618160660,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_gid",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "unspecified",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "GA1.2.84654125.1618001510",
    "id": 4
    },
    {
    "domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
    "expirationDate": 1649537510,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ym_d",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "3123432534",

"id": 5
 },
 {
"domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1618146260,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "_ym_isad",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "no_restriction",
"secure": true,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "1",
"id": 6
},
{
"domain": ".cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1649537510,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "_ym_uid",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "no_restriction",
"secure": true,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "53452324",
"id": 7
},
{
"domain": ".www.cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1649541131.924992,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": true,
"name": "__ddgid",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "FFDSertewt2454543",
"id": 8
},
{
"domain": ".www.cyberforum.ru",
"expirationDate": 1618091531.925059,
"hostOnly": false,
"httpOnly": true,
"name": "__ddgmark",
"path": "/",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": false,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "F43245345Gfg",
"id": 9
 },
 {
"domain": "www.cyberforum.ru",
"hostOnly": true,
"httpOnly": false,
"name": "cfdup_timestamp",
"path": "/csharp-beginners",
"sameSite": "unspecified",
"secure": false,
"session": true,
"storeId": "0",
"value": "432545326435",
"id": 10
}
]}
```

Сам объект:

```
    public class Cookie
    {
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public float expirationDate { get; set; }
        public bool hostOnly { get; set; }
        public bool httpOnly { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string sameSite { get; set; }
        public bool secure { get; set; }
        public bool session { get; set; }
        public string storeId { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

Ну и работа с объектом:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string json = "Тут JSON объект";
        Cookie jsonObject;
        jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cookie>(json);
        foreach (var jsonData in jsonObject.data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(jsonData.domain);//Вывод всех доменов в JSON
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что речь шла не об [этом классе](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.cookie?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: Почему-то даже не подумал об этом)
Ну, в любом случае я просто повторил функционал этого класса, спасибо за замечание.